# What is hyperledger composer playground wallet?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Please explain the concept of wallet in playground. 
I cannot find information for this in documentation.

Answer (score 1):

"Wallet" is how we describe the contents of the `~/.hfc-key-store/` or `~/.composer-credentials/` directory.

This directory is used by the HLF Node SDK as the default store for user credentials (public and private certificates).

In addition to the certs, Composer **maps** the certificates to Composer participant identities (in the identity registry), so that when a transaction is submitted (authenticated using a Fabric certificate) the associated Composer participant can be retrieved by the runtime (see the `getCurrentParticipant()` API). This mapping from cert to participant is managed using the `composer identity` CLI commands, or can be created in Playground using the interface.

We are working on a new UI design to manage certificates, connection profiles and identity mapping which should roll out over the coming weeks.